# How to grab these values with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Im trying to parse the following `HTML`:

```
<div class="content">
    <h3>
                                Kontaktuppgifter</h3>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Postadress:
            </th>
            <td>
                Platteb....
                <br/>44497 SVE....
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Telefon:
            </th>
            <td>
                01-.......

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I want to grab `td 1`, `td 2` and `td 3`
However `td 3` is not always present.

This is what i got so far:

```
def ParsePage(threadName, page_url):
    r  = requests.get(page_url)
    print "\n--------------------\n"
    print "Parsing page: " + r.url
    data = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

    divs = soup.findAll('div', { "class" : "content" })
    for tag in divs:
        divds = tag.findAll('td')   
        print divds
```

For some reason this just prints the whole div

Comment: Do you mean 'returns' as in prints the whole div, or are you missing a return statement?

Comment: Sorry i ment as in prints

Comment: It worked for me also!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have a typo somewhere, the code worked for me:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(your_html)
div = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "content"})

for tag in div: print tag.findAll("td")
#printed:
[<td>
                Platteb....
                <br/>44497 SVE....
            </td>, <td>
                01-.......

            </td>]
```